# Error on pushing to remote Git repo, denied with remote end hanging up

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

What privileges or permissions do I need to set in a Git repo in order to create a remote branch?

When I try to push my changes to the remote repo, I get this error:

> fatal: Upload denied for project 'sampleproject'
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
>   Killed by signal 1.

Comment: The default behaviour of git is to deny push.  Please check if the variable, receive.denyCurrentBranch is set to "refuse" (in config file) at the remote repo.

Comment: Too little information. Where is the repo? How was it set up? What authentication is used? Is it a bare repo?

Answer (score 0):

```
 "fatal: Upload denied for project"
```

This is a Gerrit error message (like you can see in that blog post "[Managing Git branch level permissions with TeamForge and Gerrit](http://blogs.collab.net/teamforge/managing-git-branch-level-permissions-with-teamforge-and-gerrit)")
You need to access the Gerrit access table to check the right associated to the remote branch you want to push to.

[image: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/xpzWuqnLOrsWr2mB04C1tRWHRxyys7jcgbG-N3WsMAPwMqC8HiFRbYgXBsJ9h0MOI1pt9bsVgaAelQ5taC2oRq78OBGSFV6pMJWA4_HEP9yah0AhqrRH]

It is documented in "[`Documentation/error-upload-denied.txt`](https://github.com/atdt/gerrit/blob/master/Documentation/error-upload-denied.txt)":

With this error message Gerrit rejects to push a commit if the
pushing user has no upload permissions for the project to which the
push was done.

There are two possibilities how to continue in this situation:

- contact one of the project owners and request upload permissions for the project ([access right](https://github.com/atdt/gerrit/blob/master/Documentation/access-control.txt#L571))
- export your commit as a patch using the [`git format-patch`] command and provide the patch file to one of the project owners